# Question about finding where the function increases and decreases on $f(x)=\frac 1{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x)=\frac 1{x}, x\geq 1$

I have been staring at this equation for a bit. Things I'm confused on.

the derivative of this is: $f'(x)= \frac {-1}{x^2}$ now, how am I supposed to find where this derivative increases/decreases? Do I find the critical points first? by setting the derivative to 0? or do I solve it like $\frac {-1}{x^2} > 0$ cross multiply to make it: 
$-1>x^2$ and if so once I square this does it make the result x=-1, x= 1? I'm really lost here and it seems like it should be easier.

does setting the derivative to > or < or = and solving for the x give a critical point?

Comment: What is $f(x)$? $y=f(x)$?

Comment: @npisinp Did that help?

Comment: The derivative of $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is $\dfrac{-2}{x^3}$ not $\dfrac{-1}{x^2}$

Comment: @npisinp sorry, I mis wrote it. the original function is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that intervals of increase and decrease of $f$ correspond to intervals of positivity and negativity of $f'$, and critical points of $f$ are where the roots of $f'$ are. Try graphing the function $-\frac{1}{x^2}$ using software. Where is the function positive, where is it negative, and where are its roots (if it has any)?